# Is it possible to milk carriers for infinite money?

Tags: sunrider

Carriers spawn ryders, so far it seems they have an endless supply of them, making them a priority target.

However, as one can learn in early missions, it is advantageous to not win the mission by completing the objectives as soon as possible, but to destroy all enemies, because that way the earnings can be maximized.

So, if one keeps one enemy carrier intentionally alive, and destroys every other enemy unit, is it possible to endlessly milk that carrier, by destroying the ryders it spawns? Theoretically, doing it for thousands of turns and only finishing it when one is really bored, one could get enough money to instantly buy all upgrades.